# Shortening javascript Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to shorten the code below. I have shown the first 5 if statements. I will have a total of 10 when I am done.

EDIT: FORGOT THE MOUSEMOVE PART

```
$("#bar").mousemove(function(e){
    var vb = $(this);
           if(e.pageX <=467 &&  e.pageX > 457){
            vb.attr("src","images2/vb10.png");
            vol =10;
          }
          if(e.pageX <=457 && e.pageX > 447){
            vb.attr("src","images2/vb9.png");
            vol=9;
          }
          if(e.pageX <=447 && e.pageX > 437){
            vb.attr("src","images2/vb8.png");
            vol=8;
          }
          if(e.pageX <=437 && e.pageX > 427){
            vb.attr("src","images2/vb7.png");
            vol=7;
          }
          if(e.pageX <=427 && e.pageX > 417){
            vb.attr("src","images2/vb6.png");
            vol=6
          }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the script suposed to do? If looks specific to the page changing or when it loads. You could look into a switch, but thats a lot of checks. Why do you need them every 10 pixels?

Comment: I don't know about shortening, but you should definitely use `else if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#bar").mousemove(function(e){
    var vol = Math.min( Math.ceil( (e.pageX - 7) / 10 ) - 36, 10 );
    $(this).attr("src","images2/vb"+vol+".png");
});
```

The Math library contains some optimized browser functions to help you with numbers.  The first statement takes the x coord, subtracts 7 and divides by 10 to turn 467 into 46, 457 into 45 and 458 into 45.1.  Math.ciel rounds this up, turning 458 into 46.  We then subtract 36 to get 10, and assign the smaller of the output of the above computation and the number 10 (the largest number).  We can use vol to make the image string.

Comment: You can shorten it further using [jscompress.com](http://www.jscompress.com/) to: `$("#bar").mousemove(function(a){var b=Math.ceil((a.pageX-7)/10)-36;$(this).attr("src","images2/vb"+b+".png")})` :)

Comment: I tried that add it alerted 12. The images are only 1 through 10.

Comment: Added min to the vol calculation.

Comment: Works great. That is some beautiful code. Could you please add comments explaining how it works.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation it helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use arithmetic to simplify the code.  Division on e.pageX should let you derive the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#bar').mousemove(function (e) { 
    $(this).attr("src", "image2/vb" + (vol = (e.pageX-367)/10|0) + ".png");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the shortened code. Not sure what's your real code does, but this is appropriate for what you have posted. I hope it is self-explanatory to you.

```
var vb = $(this),
    max = 467,
    frequency = 10, // difference between (467, 458), (457, 448) and so on...(your if conditions)
    maxVol = 10;

/* Find the range in which e.pageX falls. This will return, for example, if e.pageX was 460, then pageXband is 0.
 * If e.pageX is 437, then pageXband is 4 and so on.
 */
var pageXband = parseInt((max - e.pageX) / frequency); 

vol = maxVol - pageXband; // 'vol' is the difference between maxVol and pageXband.
vb.attr("src","images2/vb"+vol+".png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got several good answers already showing how to do it using arithmetic, but just to allow for a hypothetical situation where the ranges for each case are all different and thus don't fit into a convenient formula you can still shorten the code somewhat given the two values you set in each case are directly related (although it's not clear what you are using `vol` for): just set `vol` in each branch and then at the end use that to set the image source. Also, although it doesn't make the code shorter, you should use `else if` so that you don't evaluate every condition.

```
$("#bar").mousemove(function(e){
    var vol;
    if (e.pageX <=467 && e.pageX > 457)
       vol=10;
    else if (e.pageX <=457 && e.pageX > 447)
       vol=9;
    else if (e.pageX <=447 && e.pageX > 437)
       vol=8;
    // etc

    $(this).attr("src","images2/vb" + vol + ".png");
});
```

And speaking of not evaluating every condition, if the ranges are contiguous you don't need to test the upper *and* lower bounds each time:

```
$("#bar").mousemove(function(e){
    var vol;
    if (e.pageX > 467 || e.pageX < someMinimumValue)
       return; // or set default vol = ?
    else if (e.pageX > 457)
       vol=10;
    else if (e.pageX > 447)
       vol=9;
    else if (e.pageX > 437)
       vol=8;
    // etc

    $(this).attr("src","images2/vb" + vol + ".png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its good for regular and ir-regular intervals,

```
$("#bar").mousemove(function(e){
    var vol = decide(e.pageX);
    $(this).attr("src","images2/vb" + vol + ".png");

});

function decide (val1) {
    switch (true) {
         case val1 >= 457 && val1 <= 467 : return 10;
         case val1 >= 447 && val1 <= 457 : return 9;
         case val1 >= 437 && val1 <= 447 : return 8;
         case val1 >= 427 && val1 <= 437 : return 7;
         case val1 >= 417 && val1 <= 427 : return 6;
         default : return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `break` statements after `return` statements.

Comment: yup you are right. but it's good practice to use breaks in switch case

Comment: It's standard practice not to include a redundant break statement for a case that has a return, especially when every case has a return.